# Fixed Income free research available online

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, research, econometrics, macro-economics

As from the title, I would like to know where it is possible to find free research focused on fixed income markets' themes and topics, such as interest rates, credit risk related fundamentals, new issues and so on.

«Why isn't [**SSRN**](http://www.ssrn.com/) sufficient?» one could ask me; well, I'm looking for something which is more oriented to analyse present economic and financial events and less to build another stochastic model or neural networks' default probability, and such things.

Despite of this, however, a quantitative approach to research would be really appreciated, but I would be happy to find even just a few generic research sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of quant related blogs out there, some of which contain relatively sophisticated content, others less so. Have a look at the following, which aggregates blogs:

[MoneyScience](http://moneyscience.com)

Otherwise I could point you to bank/sell-side research. Have a look at the freely available Reuters Messenger (RM), they maintain channels where you can be permissioned as long as you work in some professional financial-industry capacity. (www.fxww.com should have more information if you find difficulties getting the RM installed).

[Reuters Messenger](https://customers.reuters.com/download/rm/rmall.aspx)

Check out the 'FXWW' channel in particular.

Comment: Ah, this is why your previous comments suddenly disappeared :) I will give a look at Reuters Messenger meanwhile, thank you.